# How to Debug "Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated XXX) (tried to allocate XXXXX bytes)"?

Tags: debugging, out-of-memory, php

Looking through StackOverflow I realized **out-of-memory-errors** are a common problem. **As suggested by others it can under some circumstances be managed by increasing the memory limit in the php.ini.But often this doesn't solve the error as there is a problem within the coding.**

What are most common sources of this error? How do you design your code to avoid it? **How do you approach debugging such an error?**

So far I know as sources:

- indefinite loops
- fetching large amount of db-data into a variable (possibly it helps to unset vars after using them, if it's more than one?)

Comment: Usually this is due to a very long running loop that allocates some memory for each pass, memory that isn't released until after the loop finishes. Could you provide some of the code at and around line 224?

Comment: Are you the administrator of your server? If so, what kind of box are we talking about, is it a Linux system orperhaps Windows?

Comment: @Yasmen when the PHP script runs it needs certain amount of memory. The more data you handle in your script - more memory will be required in order to handle it. Sometimes you need to unset non-used variables in order to free the memory. If you don't have anything useless in your script - "increase the memory limit" even more

Comment: @Yasmen: Do you have the Devel module (or other debugging module) installed? Devel is a notorious resource hog, as are other debuggers/profilers for Drupal

Comment: If you have a specific question about determining memory consumption in PHP, feel free to ask. However, this question (as asked) can't be answered by anyone but you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course.

You have to get your /xxxxx/xxxxx.xxx script and sort things out related to the operation performed on the line 22.
And make it less memory consuming.

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 solutions

If

- your website has a lot of traffic
- your server is used to do some memory-intensive stuff (generating PDF/image, etc.)

Then it's normal for the server to run out of memory if there simply is too much people simultaneously on your website. The only solution is to increase it. For a website that count a lot of visitor per day, 550M is between low and average amount.

But if your website has only few traffic, like a small company website, then you might have a problem. Check what processes are eating the memory - using `top`or `htop` for example - and act accordingly.

If it's PHP that is consumming too much RAM, usually this kind of error is caused by an infinite loop, or a long one, like extracting a lot of data from the DB, creating object with each of these records, without freeing memory.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote(s) ?

Comment: I didn't downvote but I would guess it's because of this statement: "it's normal that it runs out of memory". Saying that high-traffic websites written in PHP frequently fall over due to out of memory errors (and this is in some way 'normal') is simply not true in my experience

Comment: I didn't downvote either but the phrase "real website" seems a little iffy. Small websites are real websites too! However, I do think it's a good point that PHP doesn't have to be the culprit. There are a good many processes running on any server at any given time, all of which are potential memory hogs!

Comment: @Clive: you're right, I'm not clear enough. I meant "normal" like in "it's normal for the server to run out of memory if there simply is too much people simultaneously on your website". I'm editing.

Comment: @toon81 Edited to reflect what I meant by "real website" =)