# Magento. How to debug Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated.... )

Tags: magento, memory, memory-management

I have found a lot of topics here with the similar question. But I find all off them useless.
I even found one good topic with the similar question which I'd like to ask:
[How to Debug "Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated XXX) (tried to allocate XXXXX bytes)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309007/how-to-debug-fatal-error-out-of-memory-allocated-xxx-tried-to-allocate-xxxx?answertab=oldest#tab-top)
Don't know why this topic was closed. The problem exist and I didn't found in google any algorithms how to detect this problem.

Usually problem with insufficient memory appear when exist some loop. When some code run many times before the memory not disappear. And increasing memory will not help!!!

I'd like here to collect ways how to detect the loop. For example make some log messages, or debug SQL queries. Any ways, which can be helpful to detect the issue. This problem can be with any extension, with combination of two extensions. And the first way which I can offer from me:

**- Disable parts/modules/themes of magento**

(it the only what I use and it didn't help me last time)

---

For example here is where I faced with the following error:

/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 206

```
public function setData($key, $value=null)
{
    if(is_array($key)) {
        $this->_data = $key;
    } else {
        $this->_data[$key] = $value;
    }
    return $this;
}
```

very very old magento 1.3.2.4

after trying to create invoice.

Comment: Did u try to use xdebug to run a mem profile on your code?

Comment: Current memory_limit on stock Magento running 20k products is in the 256M-512M range. Memory limit goes up with the success of your site, ie, more customers, more resources needed. Debugging is only indicated if you're not running stock and have created a module that's got a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you turn developer mode on, ensure logging is enabled (system->configuration->developer), and start sprinkling the core code liberally with log messages:

```
Mage::log("Some message about which function you are in ".$someHelpfulVariable, null, 'mylogfile.log');
```

Do you have a trace for this error? Adding the trace to your question would be helpful. Put some logging code in each of the functions in the trace so that you can see what is leading up to the fatal error.

Comment: In that case better use

Mage::log( (string)new Exception(), false, 'somelog.log', true);

But in my case this the process stop at one time. It will be helpful if somebody recommend where to use this.

Comment: No, you don't understand, I mean you need to put it everywhere to find out when your code is stopping. I think you must know what URL you call to trigger the fatal error - that gives you a route and a layout, so start there. Stick in ten logs numbered one to ten throughout front.php and action.php and as you narrow it down move the logging into the models and blocks until you pinpoint the line that is causing your error. If you tell us the URL and give us the full error code we might be able to advise further. The only time I fatal out of memory is if I try to do var_dump($someLargeObject);